# Two related but opposite variables, how to calculate a score for them?

Tags: statistics

I want to create two related values from similar data that actually mean opposites.

I'm wanting to create two values that describes how efficient someone is at a game, the values should describe how deadly they are and also how good they are at surviving damage.

At first I just used `damage dealt/kills` to create the first value and then `damage taken/deaths` for the second, which is fine since it's easy to compare the the two values, however the problem I have is that low damage dealt ratio is a good thing but a low damage taken ratio is also a good thing.

What I would like is for a high value in both to be a good thing but also keep them comparable, how would I go about this?

A high score for the deaths variable would involve a lower number of deaths and a high number of damage taken while a high score for the kills variable would involve a high number of kills for a low number of damage dealt.

Comment: Is the inverse of your measures appropriate in this context, _deaths/damage taken_ and _kills/damage dealt_?

Comment: Yes that would be totally fine and is actually what I'm using now to avoid any divide by zero problems if there are no deaths or kills in a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inverse of your measures:

*deaths/damage taken*

*kills/damage dealt*

**Edit based on OP comment:**

You can modify the above expressions so that they satisfy your requirements as such:

*damage taken/deaths*

*kills/damage dealt*

If you want to prevent dividing by zero on the first one you can go

*damage taken/(deaths+1)* or assign an otherwise *max_value* to this scenario.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I did not explain clearly enough, however this solution runs into a similar problem that lower number of deaths with the same amount of damage has a lower score than a higher number deaths with the same amount of damage. 

The perfect solution would be a low number of deaths with a high damage taken = higher score and a higher number of kills with a low damage dealt = higher score

Comment: Editted my answer according to your explanation.

Comment: Any suggestion for bringing the two numbers closer together? I've times the kills/damage by x and divided the damage/deaths by y but I've just chosen arbitrary values that just so happen to work, is there a mathematical way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by closer together? That for _damage dealt=damage taken_ and _kills=deaths_ both ratios are the same?

Comment: Yes, and since there are two sides in each match one sides kills/damage would be inversely proportional to the others damage/deaths.

Comment: Since you enforce that the measure for defense (_damage taken/deaths_) and the measure for attack (_kills/damage dealt_) are somewhat inversely proportional between themselves to satisfy the requirement stated above, there is no point in trying to enforce that they should be equal at the same _damage_ and _kills_ since they will be inversely proportional. You could multiply both by a different constant and get them to be equal for a given reference value of _damage_ and _kills_ but I don't know if that's any useful.